# AWS EC2 running Ubuntu 18 VPN will not connect (network manager?)

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws

I am attempting to run a 3rd party VPN (Hotspot Shield) on my EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18.

When I run the the connect command, I get an error for Hotspot Shield client. I have attached the corresponding system log.
I have tried using two other VPNs (NordVPN and Wireguard) and both cause my ubuntu box to crash when attempting to create a connection.

It strongly appears that the issue is with my EC2 instance, not the client. The instance currently allows all inbound and outbound traffic.

Any insight that could be given is greatly appreciated!

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-208:~$ hotspotshield connect
can't establish VPN connection. Please check your system journals
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-208:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
May 29 01:48:34 ip-172-31-38-208 NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1590716914.5407] audit: op="device-managed" arg="managed:1" pid=3170 uid=1000 result="success"
May 29 01:48:34 ip-172-31-38-208 systemd-timesyncd[604]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 29 01:48:34 ip-172-31-38-208 networkd-dispatcher[854]: WARNING:Unknown index 3 seen, reloading interface list
May 29 01:48:34 ip-172-31-38-208 systemd-timesyncd[604]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 29 01:48:38 ip-172-31-38-208 hotspotshield[3170]: nm_wait_for_device: it was not possible to activate hss0 device. Please make sure NetworkManager is running and it's the current system network renderer
May 29 01:48:38 ip-172-31-38-208 systemd-timesyncd[604]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 29 01:48:38 ip-172-31-38-208 hotspotshield[3170]: linux_cm_new: linux_tun_new
May 29 01:48:38 ip-172-31-38-208 hotspotshield[3170]: CM: failed to start connectivity module
May 29 01:48:38 ip-172-31-38-208 NetworkManager[864]: <info>  [1590716918.1779] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/hss0, iface: hss0)
May 29 01:48:38 ip-172-31-38-208 systemd-timesyncd[604]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

Output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

ifupdown is said to be at current version when I apt install it

Output of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml.`:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6
            set-name: eth0
```

I implemented the changes suggested by @hyennama, but unfortunately it did not do the trick.
After implementation, and attempting to connect, the system log showed:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-28:~$ hotspotshield connect
can't establish VPN connection. Please check your system journals
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-28:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
May 31 23:12:00 ip-172-31-21-28 systemd-timesyncd[579]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 31 23:12:00 ip-172-31-21-28 networkd-dispatcher[841]: WARNING:Unknown index 6 seen, reloading interface list
May 31 23:12:00 ip-172-31-21-28 NetworkManager[877]: <info>  [1590966720.2418] audit: op="device-managed" arg="managed:1" pid=1576 uid=1000 result="success"
May 31 23:12:00 ip-172-31-21-28 systemd-timesyncd[579]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
May 31 23:12:04 ip-172-31-21-28 hotspotshield[1576]: nm_wait_for_device: it was not possible to activate hss0 device. Please make sure NetworkManager is running and it's the current system network renderer
May 31 23:12:04 ip-172-31-21-28 systemd-timesyncd[579]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
May 31 23:12:04 ip-172-31-21-28 NetworkManager[877]: <info>  [1590966724.0845] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/hss0, iface: hss0)
May 31 23:12:04 ip-172-31-21-28 hotspotshield[1576]: linux_cm_new: linux_tun_new
May 31 23:12:04 ip-172-31-21-28 hotspotshield[1576]: CM: failed to start connectivity module
May 31 23:12:04 ip-172-31-21-28 systemd-timesyncd[579]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

And the debug log showed:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-28:/etc/netplan$ sudo netplan --debug generate
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.545: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.545: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.545: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.545: br0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.545: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.546: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.546: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.546: Generating output files..
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.546: NetworkManager: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:1617): DEBUG: 23:13:19.546: NetworkManager: definition br0 is not for us (backend 1)
```

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-28:~$ ifconfig
as0t0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.224.1  netmask 255.255.248.0  destination 172.27.224.1
        inet6 fe80::d062:c8f4:acd2:4007  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9  bytes 432 (432.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

as0t1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.232.1  netmask 255.255.248.0  destination 172.27.232.1
        inet6 fe80::6444:cb31:f77d:a263  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 200  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9  bytes 432 (432.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.31.21.28  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.31.31.255
        inet6 fe80::4bf:cff:fe4a:a5d6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 829  bytes 110235 (110.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 752  bytes 122774 (122.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1115  bytes 161707 (161.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1145  bytes 168052 (168.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 164  bytes 15789 (15.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 164  bytes 15789 (15.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output of `ip a`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-28:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.21.28/20 brd 172.31.31.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 2171sec preferred_lft 2171sec
    inet6 fe80::4bf:cff:fe4a:a5d6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: as0t0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 200
    link/none
    inet 172.27.224.1/21 brd 172.27.231.255 scope global as0t0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d062:c8f4:acd2:4007/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: as0t1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 200
    link/none
    inet 172.27.232.1/21 brd 172.27.239.255 scope global as0t1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6444:cb31:f77d:a263/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Be sure to format the pasted text with the {} icon to make it human-readable. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the question with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon AWS EC2 requires a bridged input. You don't show this in your /etc/netplan/*.yaml.

Here's a new .yaml that should probably replace yours...

**Note**: Save a copy of your current .yaml just in case we need to go back.

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6
      set-name: eth0
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      macaddress: 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6
      interfaces:
        - eth0
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot` # mandatory

Now try and get your VPN to work.

Comment: Ive tried what you have suggested, thank you putting in the time!
Unfortunately it didnt do the trick.

Comment: @eliasthe Contact the Amazon folks and see if they're willing/able to help you. There may be a technical reason why VPN will/won't work with EC2.

Comment: I will! I have followed VPN installation tutorials on EC2, in which the VPN works without hassle. In case you have any more insight to spare, I have updated my question with the new system log after implementing you suggestion

Comment: @eliasthe I just reviewed your latest logs. It's looking for NetworkManager, not networkd!

Comment: It returns the same thing that it did before (detailed in my post). So no change

Comment: @eliasthe In the Hotspot docs, does it indicate ONLY working with NetworkManager... nothing about systemd-networkd?

Comment: I was not aware of any stipulation in Hotspot about Network manager. I will check though. Should be noted ive tried two other vpn clients to the same result

Comment: @eliasthe Show me `ifconfig` or `ip a`.

Comment: added them to original post

Comment: @eliasthe I believe that the current .yaml are correctly showing bro and eth0 devices, required for an AWS EC2, but I don't recognize as0t0 and as0t1 devices. I guess I'm over my head here. I might suggest something that will only make things worse. Contact the Amazon folks and see if they can help. Please keep me posted.

Comment: thank u I will!!